# Jetson TK1 can not find USB port ( Kinect/RPLidar)

Tags: ros, jetson-tk1, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS on Jetson TK1. When I connected sensors (like Kinect, RPlidar ) to the USB port and list the device, the device did not appear as expected ($ ls /dev/ttyUSB* ).  How to deal with this?

Cheers,
Rickardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221137/jetson-tk1-can-not-find-usb-port-(-kinect/rplidar)/) by [Rickardo Leos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3712/rickardo-leos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-19**:
How are they listed? Also can you post output of `lsusb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Rickardo,

I had the same issue, and what the problem was is the SERIAL and FTDI kernel modules were not built for the jetson TX 1for some reason. the Jetson TX1 uses the arm64 arch and you would have to build these drivers from source and install them. check out the Jetson forums: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/board/164/jetson-tx1/

---

Originally posted by [zastrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/26045/zastrix/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0